# MS-access SQL pasted in sqlite but returns error

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to run the following, which is OK in MS-ACCESS environment, but NG in sqlite environment.  Error says: "Uncaught error" "unrecognized toke:"90Days."

```
SELECT invoices.CustomerId, invoices.InvoiceDate 
FROM invoices 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT invoices.CustomerId, Min(InvoiceDate)+90 as 90Days, Min(InvoiceDate)+120 as 120Days 
FROM invoices GROUP BY invoices.CustomerId) AS q2 ON invoices.CustomerId = q2.CustomerId 
WHERE (((invoices.InvoiceDate) Between [90Days] And [120Days])) ORDER BY invoices.CustomerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

`90Days` is not a valid name, so you [must quote it](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

```
... as [90Days], ... as [120Days]
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for advice.  when I made that change, the error message has gone. Yet, no result while MS-Access returned 22 records.  Wonder if there is still anything missing. Best regards.